# HWinfo64 - Temperature report accuracy

Tags: cpu, motherboard, fan, temperature

I recently got a secondhand PC with a 4790 i7 and Z97p Killer motherboard and decided to try a little overclocking. I have it boosted to 3.9GHz, but the fan sounds very loud and in the hwInfo64 readouts, the temps are in the mid-30s, reporting no throttling:
[image: hwinfo readouts]

- Should I bother with overclocking?
- Is this temperature okay, and if so, why is the fan so loud now?

  - Is there a way to limit the fan speed to quiet it down?

Comment: Use [SpeedFan - Access temperature sensor in your computer](https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) to control your fans.

Comment: Ok thanks I used that years ago but somewhere stored in my memory was info telling me not to use that app. Also is it wise to slow them down purely based on the readings I see in HWinfo? (thanks for the help)

Comment: HWInfo is for reporting only.

Comment: This worked fine. Speedfan was on 100% cpu fan. I changed it to 80% now much quieter and temps did not change at all (perhaps by 1C). My only worry now is if I am gaming or 3d rendering and it needed to go up for a short burst at 100% fanspeed. Is it a better idea to have it at 100%? (For the record, the 100% fanspeed started IMMEDIATELY after overclock -ie. the very moment I turned the PC on after o/c. It remained at 100% entire time until I forced it down using Speedfan)

Comment: I think it's possible to configure a fan profile but I've never needed to do it ...